# Hobbyist way to connect to USB-C/A device from iOS device with or without MFi

Tags: ios, usb

If I have a generic USB device (can be a keyboard, an Arduino board, etc), and I want to connect it to my iOS device, can I access it from the iOS device specifically through an app I am developing in Swift? I'm looking for general information on this, and having trouble finding any myself. To be clear, I am developing an app for personal use and want to be able to access information from the device similar to how on a Mac you can access the `/dev/` directory for these types of devices.

`ExternalAccessory` is, to my knowledge, only usable for hardware that contains certain chips that allow it be accessed that way. And plus this is only through the MFi program, which I don't have access to.

If this is a duplicate or I've missed something, kindly point me in the right direction and I will delete this post.

Comment: You will find it much easier if you use BLE and Core Bluetooth.  There are several low-cost Arduino compatible BLE modules.

Comment: You can use [this cable](http://redpark.com/lightning-serial-cable-l2-db9v/) to get a serial port for personal use (not App Store)